# sql query for minus operation

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT flight_id, depart, arr, price 
FROM user.flightdb t2 LEFT JOIN
     user.booking t1
     ON t1.flightID = t2.flight_id
WHERE t2.source = 1 and t2.dest = 4 and
      t1.date = "02/02/2016" and t1.flightID IS NULL;
```

I want to select those flight_id from flightdb(table) who should have source and destination as given and out of them which do not appear in the booking(table) at a particular date.

so what will be the query in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `left join`, but the conditions on the second table need to be in the `on` clause.  Also, you should use a proper date format:

```
SELECT flight_id, depart, arr, price 
FROM user.flightdb t2 LEFT JOIN
     user.booking t1
     ON t1.flightID = t2.flight_id and t1.date = '2016-02-02'
WHERE t2.source = 1 and t2.dest = 4 and t1.flightID IS NULL;
```

Comment: ohh got it thank you so much, it killed my whole day.can u just tell where was i wrong logically?

Comment: One of the two things I mentioned:  The conditions on `booking` need to be in the `on` clause (for a left join) and possibly the date format is misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FOLLOWING QUERY

```
 SELECT flight_id, depart, arr, price 
      FROM user.flightdb t2 LEFT JOIN
       user.booking t1 ON t1.flightID = t2.flight_id 
    and t2.source = 1 and t2.dest = 4  AND  
         t1.date = "02/02/2016" WHERE  t1.flightID IS NULL;
```

Comment: please check this and let me know

Comment: it's giving some extra data also